# How to design MVVM in this situation

Tags: c#, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a project with three Views:

- ChartsView
- NewsView
- SettingsView

Essentially, the GraphsViewModel downloads some data to be represented as Chart, the NewsViewModel downloads some feed and represents it as a list. Both has a timer that decides how often download data, so there is also a SettingsViewModel associated to SettingsView in which the user could decide this setting and some others.

The problem is: how to set up the SettingsViewModel?

The first thing I did was putting inside SettingsView something like this:

```
<Pivot>

    <PivotItem DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=GetNewsView}" Header="News Settings">
        ...
    </PivotItem>


    <PivotItem DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=GetChartView}" Header="Chart Settings">
        ...
    </PivotItem>

</Pivot>
```

Is It a bad practice? Somewhere I read that to apply the MVVM correctly, I should use only ViewModel per View. But in this case it seems (to me) intricate to put the setting into a SettingsViewModel and send via Message (MVVM Light) to the other Views the values they need. (In this case the settings needed to let the two main views to work are defined into the them)

Am I thinking wrong?

Comment: Yes you are correct.It should be always one View - one view model(internally this can interact with n different view models).

Comment: Do you want to share data between viewmodels? Create shared object :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is as many solutions for this scenario as many developers live on the planet :)

Here is how I would do it:

I would create some object to store the settings:

```
public class SettingsModel
{
    public TimeSpan DownloadInterval {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

and share singleton instance of the class among viewmodels.
Here i use dependency injection to do it so:

```
public class NewsViewModel
{
     public NewsViewModel(SettingsModel settings)
     {
         //do whatever you need with the setting
         var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
         timer.Interval = settings.DownloadInterval;

         //alternativly you can use something like SettingsModel.Current to access the instance
        // or AppContext.Current.Settings
        // or ServiceLocator.GetService<SettingsModel>()
     }
}

public class SettingsViewModel
{
     public SettingsViewModel(SettingsModel settings)
     {
        Model = settings;
     }

     public SettingsModel Model{get; private set;}
}
```